# Passing parameter in get ajax in Yii2

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

Basically i using ajax in Select2.

The code is like this :

```
<?php $url = \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['/finance/job-order/search-job-order/']);?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'job_order_id')->label(false)->widget(Select2::className(), [
     'data' => $modelJobOrder,
     'options' => [
         'placeholder' => 'Pilih Job Order'
      ],
     'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
     'pluginEvents' => [
       'change' => "
            function(){
                var selected = this.value;

                $.get('" . $url . "?id=selected', function(response){
                   alert(response);
                });
            }
        "
     ]
]) 
?>
```

But the route has created like this :

```
/finance/job-order/search-job-order?id=selected
```

Not the value,

```
/finance/job-order/search-job-order?id={value that selected}
```

Please advise

Comment: Better to use [Kartik depdrop](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop)

Comment: You are using selected as string. If you want to get its value, you should concatenate it to the string url you're generating. But, as Insane Skull says, you'll be better off using Dep Drop plugin

Answer (score 0):

You are not concatenating the value in the url string properly. It should be:

```
$.get('" . $url . "?id=' + selected, function(response) {
```

Aditionally, You can pass params to your ajax request this way:

```
$.get('" . $url . "', {id: selected}, function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```